# Turn off Yahoo News notifications without turning off email notifications

Tags: yahoo-mail

I just recently downloaded the Yahoo app to get my email on, and I am constantly getting notifications from Yahoo News. I want to turn off the news notifications but *not* the mail notifications.

I turned off all notifications, but I get time-sensitive email messages and I am missing a lot of deadlines with the notifications off, so I turned it back on.

But now I'm killing my battery because I am constantly having to check my phone because I never know if it's an email or news that I don't care about.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is there an option to mark emails from Yahoo News as spam?

Answer (score 4):

The news notification can be set inside the Yahoo Mail app itself.

1. Open the left navigation drawer (e.g. by swiping from left to right, or tapping the "hamburger" icon on the top-left)
2. Tap **Settings** at the bottom
3. Under **General**, select **Notifications**
4. Under **News notification settings**, tap **Enable notifications** to switch it off/on

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Sound & notification ---> App notifications.
Turn off the app you don't want to raise Notifications

Also see Advanced option if any application can read notifications and should be allowed or not.

Comment: If I do that, it turns ALL notifications for Yahoo off, and I only want to turn off the news notifications. I still have to get "new message" notifications.

Comment: I guess, you will have to see into Yahoo app's settings for that. If they haven't provided that, then you should contact Yahoo for that.

Answer (score 0):

Select the three bars next to "inbox".  Select "Settings" in the list.  In the General section select "Notifications".  Scroll to bottom to see News Notification section.  Turn off "Breaking News".

Answer (score 0):

when you see the alert, press and hold for a few seconds until you see two icons. tap the one for notifications (looks like a bell with an "x" through it).